# XSD schema - how to create dependency between elements at different levels

Tags: xml, xsd

For the below XSD, I want to achieve dependency between elements at different depths. How do I modify this schema to achieve the following validation for my XML:

- If "**Info**" element is not present in XML, then element "**Value**" must be present for every "**ObjectData**"
- If element named "**Value**" is not specified in XML for one or more "**ObjectData**" elements, than element named "**Info**" must be present

  ```
      <xs:element name="Objects" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:all>
                  <xs:element name="Info" type="Info" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element name="ObjectData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:all>
                              <xs:element name="ObjType" type="ObjTypeEnum" />
                              <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                              <xs:element name="Prop" type="properties" />
                          </xs:all>
                      </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
              </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
  ```

Another way to understand the above two requirements is this,

```
if( Objects.Info.occurs == 0 )
    For-each Objectdata in Objects
        assert(ObjectData.Value.occurs == 1)

For-atleast-one ObjectData in Objects
    if ( ObjectData.Value.occurs == 0 )
        assert(Objects.Info.occurs == 1)
```

Comment: Can you use XML Schema 1.1 or Schematron? If you don't know, use an `xs:assert` element in your XSD to test for XSD 1.1, or say which tool you use for validation.

Comment: I have no understanding of xs::assert or schmeatron. How do it do it ?

Comment: Then, as I said, please tell us which tool and version of it you are using for validation. An implicit test is to put e.g. `<xsd:assert test="true()" />` in one of your type definitions.

Comment: Mathias I am using this online tool freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html. I guess its XSD 1.0. I will have to look at xs:assert feature. XSD 1.1 is new to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mathias I am using this online tool freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html. I guess its XSD 1.0. I will have to look at xs:assert feature. XSD 1.1 is new to me

Yes, the freeformatter online validator only supports XML Schema 1.0. I tested this by submitting an XSD document that contains `<xsd:assert test="true()" />` in a type definition. This resulted in:

```
S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_list' Is Invalid. 
Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.
```

This is relevant in your case because the only way to represent dependency constraints like `x if y and z, otherwise not(x)` are *assertions*. Unfortunately, assertions are an feature that is exclusive to XML Schema 1.1.

So, no, if you cannot use another tool / an XSD 1.1 validation engine to perform the validation, this is impossible.

If you can use an engine like Xerces or Saxon-EE, I'm glad to elaborate on an assertions solution in XSD 1.1. Alternatively, the same rules can be written in Schematron, another schema language.

Comment: Actually, the validation is done in my C++ xml code. It doesn't use XSD file but the code is written compliant to schema in XSD. The reason I have an xsd file is to make sure that when I create xml, it compiles with xsd before I load it in my c++ application. I am using PUGI for xml dom parsing. I guess PUGI doesnt have any sort of capability to validate XML against xsd

Comment: @nurabha I agree, pugixml very likely does not support validation. Then, your only options are 1) to do without your dynamic rules or 2) to load the XML in a C++ script and then use C++ code to assert the rules you have in mind, e.g. with the help of XPath expressions. I'm sure pugixml can handle XPath expressions.

Comment: Herr Müller, Thanks for the feedback and help. I will do the needful